# Why ngIf not hide element

Tags: angular

```
<span *ngIf="displayProgressBar">
    <c-progress-bar color='primary' [progress]=ocrProgress>
    </c-progress-bar>
</span>
```

default this variable is inicialize

```
displayProgressBar: boolean = false;
```

In some method i change value and view is display

```
someMethodExecuteFirst() {
    this.displayProgressBar = true;
}
```

next i execute second method and

```
someMethodExecuteSecond() {
    this.displayProgressBar = false;
    console.log(this.displayProgressBar); // false
}
```

but HTML view is still visible. What could be the reason ?

Comment: you've defined someMethodExecuteFirst() twice. also this.this.displayProgressBar should be this.displayProgressBar

Comment: I assume this is pseudocode, so make sure that it corresponds your actual code when posting, even after edit now, you are having two methods named `someMethodExecuteFirst` twice... ;)

Comment: Also this is not enough code to reproduce the issue, where/when do you call these methods?

Comment: firstMethod i execute when drag and drown file and second method is execute whe recive response from API

Comment: @WalterWhite and how does that code actually look like... ?

Comment: in fistMethod i put console.log() and this method is execute only one

Comment: try *ngIf="displayProgressBar == true"

Comment: When I change *ngIf to [hidden] everything working